# Reset SAS 9.4 memsize

Tags: memory-management, configuration, sas

I want change the memsize to 6GB in SAS 9.4. I have read the previous posts that I need to change the .cfg file.

I am following the instruction here but it does not work. 
http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/FAQ/SAS/MemoryAllocation.shtm.

However, my memsize is unchanged.

```
proc options group = memory; run;

SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M2


Group=MEMORY
 SORTSIZE=1073741824
               Specifies the amount of memory that is available to the
               SORT procedure.
SUMSIZE=0         Specifies a limit on the amount of memory that is available
               for data summarization procedures when class variables are
               active.
MAXMEMQUERY=0     Specifies the maximum amount of memory that is allocated
               for procedures.
MEMBLKSZ=16777216 Specifies the memory block size for Windows memory-based
               libraries.
MEMMAXSZ=2147483648
               Specifies the maximum amount of memory to allocate for
               using memory-based libraries.
LOADMEMSIZE=0     Specifies a suggested amount of memory that is needed for
               executable programs loaded by SAS.
MEMSIZE=2147483648
               Specifies the limit on the amount of virtual memory that
               can be used during a SAS session.
REALMEMSIZE=0     Specifies the amount of real memory SAS can expect to
               allocate.
NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
  real time           0.01 seconds
  cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

My SAS/OS information is as below,

```
NOTE: Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by SAS Institute Inc., Cary, NC, USA.
NOTE: SAS (r) Proprietary Software 9.4 (TS1M2)
  Licensed to UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA SYSTEM-SFA-T&R, Site 70081229.
NOTE: This session is executing on the X64_7PRO  platform.



NOTE: Updated analytical products:

  SAS/STAT 13.2
  SAS/ETS 13.2
  SAS/OR 13.2
  SAS/IML 13.2
  SAS/QC 13.2

NOTE: Additional host information:

X64_7PRO WIN 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Workstation

NOTE: SAS initialization used:
  real time           0.98 seconds
  cpu time            0.63 seconds
```

Would really appreciate some suggestions.

Thanks!

edited: 04:06PM, 9/23/2015

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I strongly recommend not setting `memsize` to zero, as this can lead to poor system performance.  Set it to a number a few GB under your total available system memory.

Comment: @Reeza Just uploaded the output

Comment: @Joe Then how to change the memsize to 4GB, then. Also it showed that MEMSIZE=2147483648, how much is that in GB term? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is 2GB. Is this 32 or 64 bit SAS?  On a desktop or a single user server or a multi user server?

Comment: And are you running SAS directly in DM mode or through EG or SAS/Connect?

Comment: So you are editing the cfg file, or you're changing your shortcut?

Comment: Just edited the cfg file. It works perfectly. It is weird, SAS disallowed me to set memsize to 0 but i can set up memsize to 6G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am following the steps here http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/FAQ/SAS/MemoryAllocation.shtm

Only some minor differences.

1. Go to C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4
   2.Copy sasv9.cfg (SAS Confugration Information)
2. Go to u:\Documents\My SAS Files\9.4
3. Paste sasv9.cfg

**Open sasv9.cfg
In the second line, type "-memsize 6g"**

5. Go to Start→All Programs→SAS then right-click on SAS 9.4 (English)
6. Select Send to→Desktop to create a shortcut
7. Go to the Desktop, right-lick on the SAS shortcut, then open Properties
8. Modify the Target. Replace the segment that says:
   -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg"
   with this one:
   -CONFIG "U:\Documents\My SAS Files\9.4\sasv9.cfg" 
   9.Click OK, then OK.
9. Invoke SAS **THROUGH the SHORTCUT ICON**
10. **You will receive a warning message ask you if you want to "make modification of your computer setting", click "Yes"**